# Vertically align on css

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Hi there im new to css3 and ive searched for hours on how to align text vertically in my navbar. i have tried every solution found here at stackoverflow but wasn't able to correct my problem. so i tought that maybe it was my code itself and decided to put it here and ask for help.

I want to know how to vertically align my navbar using css. Here is what i have so far...

```
#nav{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:80 px;
    background-image:url('images/navbar bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none; 
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#nav li{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
}

#nav a{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:114px;
    height:80px;
    background-image:url('images/btn.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
}
```

And my html look like this...

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Id deeply apreciate any help you could give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the CSS for your `#nav a` links to use `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H56zd/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot this made the trick. I tried the other two answers provided by @Kheema Pandey and (Imove) but for some reason they didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the line-height rule on your #nav li

```
#nav li{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  float:left;
  line-height: 5.5em;
}
```

Comment: One note about using the line-height to vertically center something is that it won't work with more than one line of text.

Comment: You are right...if you have more than one line of text, you need to set the ul to display table and the li with display table-cell and vertical-align to middle..that should work.

Answer (score 0):

By using 3 lines of code you may get vertically center on unknown height. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/katogipe/1/edit)**.

```
#nav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
  /*Need to add only 3 lines for vertical align*/
position: relative;
top: 30%;
transform: translateY(-30%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using vertical-align:middle at #nav a, or if it doesn't work, at #nav li.